# Adding two columns together in CSV and outputting to new CSV file

Tags: shell, command-line, awk, csv, gawk

I have a problem I have been trying to figure out:

We have a stock file CSV, which contains the stock in multiple locations.

The csv looks like this:

```
stock_no,primary,secondary,tertiary,cstock,direct
ABU0029843,1,,,5,
ABU0029934,60,,,5,
ABU0030034,,30,,5,
```

I would like the end result to look something like this (essentially summing up and removing the empty columns.)

```
stock_no,primary
ABU0029843,6
ABU0029934,65
ABU0030034,35
```

I have tried various methods with awk, but I seem to be returning values of 0

However, I am not too familiar with awk, so I am sure I am doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = ","; } NR == 1 { print $1, $2; next; } { for (x = 3; x <= NF; x++) $2 += $x;  print $1, $2 } ' file
```